# Fail to build Boost system library

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, mingw, qnx

I'm trying to build 'system' library from Boost using command:

> bjam --toolset=gcc  target-os=qnx
>   --build-dir=c:\boost_1_57_0  --build-type=complete --with-system stage

and keep getting error:

> C:\boost_1_57_0>bjam --toolset=gcc  target-os=qnx
>   --build-dir=c:\boost_1_57_0  --build-type=complete --with-system stage ...found 1 target... ...updating 1 target... config-cache.write
>   c:\boost_1_57_0\boost\bin.v2\project-cache.jam ...updated 1 target...
>
> Component configuration:
>
> ```
> - atomic                   : not building
> - chrono                   : not building
> - container                : not building
> - context                  : not building
> - coroutine                : not building
> - date_time                : not building
> - exception                : not building
> - filesystem               : not building
> - graph                    : not building
> - graph_parallel           : not building
> - iostreams                : not building
> - locale                   : not building
> - log                      : not building
> - math                     : not building
> - mpi                      : not building
> - program_options          : not building
> - python                   : not building
> - random                   : not building
> - regex                    : not building
> - serialization            : not building
> - signals                  : not building
> - system                   : building
> - test                     : not building
> - thread                   : not building
> - timer                    : not building
> - wave                     : not building
> ```
>
> ...found 205 targets... ...updating 4 targets... gcc.link.dll
>   c:\boost_1_57_0\boost\bin.v2\libs\system\build\gcc-mingw-4.8.1\debug\target-os-qnx\threading-multi\libboost_system-mgw48-mt-d-1_57.so.1.57.0
>   c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   cannot find -lrt collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> ```
> "g++"    -o "c:\boost_1_57_0\boost\bin.v2\libs\system\build\gcc-mingw-4.8.1\debug\target-os-qnx\threading-multi\libboost_system-mgw48-mt-d-1_57.so.1.57.0"
> ```
>
> -shared -Wl,--start-group "c:\boost_1_57
>   _0\boost\bin.v2\libs\system\build\gcc-mingw-4.8.1\debug\target-os-qnx\threading-multi\error_code.o"
>   -Wl,-Bstatic  -Wl,-Bdynamic -lrt -Wl,--end-group -g -pthread
>
> ...failed gcc.link.dll
>   c:\boost_1_57_0\boost\bin.v2\libs\system\build\gcc-mingw-4.8.1\debug\target-os-qnx\threading-multi\libboost_system-mgw48-mt-d-1_57.so.1.57.0...
>   ...skipped libboost_system-mgw48-mt-d-1_57.so.1.57.0 for
>   lack of
>   libboost_system-mgw48-
>   mt-d-1_57.so.1.57.0... gcc.link.dll
>   c:\boost_1_57_0\boost\bin.v2\libs\system\build\gcc-mingw-4.8.1\release\target-os-qnx\threading-multi\libboost_system-mgw48-mt-1_57.so.1.57.0
>   c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   cannot find -lrt collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> ```
> "g++"    -o "c:\boost_1_57_0\boost\bin.v2\libs\system\build\gcc-mingw-4.8.1\release\target-os-qnx\threading-multi\libboost_system-mgw48-mt-1_57.so.1.57.0"
> ```
>
> -shared -Wl,--start-group "c:\boost_1_57
>   _0\boost\bin.v2\libs\system\build\gcc-mingw-4.8.1\release\target-os-qnx\threading-multi\error_code.o"
>   -Wl,-Bstatic  -Wl,-Bdynamic -lrt -Wl,--end-group -pthread
>
> ...failed gcc.link.dll
>   c:\boost_1_57_0\boost\bin.v2\libs\system\build\gcc-mingw-4.8.1\release\target-os-qnx\threading-multi\libboost_system-mgw48-mt-1_57.so.1.57.0...
>   ...skipped libboost_system-mgw48-mt-1_57.so.1.57.0 for
>   lack of
>   libboost_system-mgw48-
>   mt-1_57.so.1.57.0... ...failed updating 2 targets... ...skipped 2
>   targets...

The rt lib seems to be missing, where can I obtain such lib to successfully compile 'system' lib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for my problem:

- First thing to do is to get MinGW and put it under C:\MinGW.
- In C:\MinGW\bin there should be gcc
- Run cmd.
- In boost (deflaut C:\boost_1_57_0) main folder
- Set path using command: 'set PATH=c:\mingw\bin;%PATH%'
- Go to the tools\build directory of your boost folder and run 'bootstrap mingw'
- To build system lib in root directory type:
- 'tools\build\b2 toolset=gcc --target-os=qnxnto --build-type=complete stage --with-system'
- .a files will be in stage\libs folder